# Eloquent - Where on relationship table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have models Store and Control:

```
class Store extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['code', 'name', 'country_id', 'active'];

    public function controls(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Control');
    }
}

class Control extends Model{
    protected $fillable = ['store_id', 'user_id', 'saved_at'];

    public function store(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Store');
    }

}
```

And now I want to get 5 stores, where the are no controls or controls are the oldest (created_at) from all the controls.

How can I make this conditions with eloquent? I know how to make it with Joins, but I want it with the "nice code".

Something like :D

```
\App\Store::with('controls')->whereNotNull('controls.created_at')->orderBy('controls.created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tried these, but I think both should work:

```
    \App\Store::whereHas('controls', function ($query) {
        $query->whereNotNull('created_at');
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    })->take(5)->get();

    \App\Store::with(['controls' => function ($query) {
        $query->whereNotNull('created_at');
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }])->take(5)->get();
```

Use the debugbar to see which one is faster.